# GNUPlot: Display less marks on x-axis?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to get less marks on the x axis to display, since it's not exactly readable as to what size those values are.

[image: Graph]

Right now I'm using the

```
set xrange [1000:1000000]
```

directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command

```
`set xtics 5e5`
```

(or some other number) to space the tics further apart. For your data it looks like three tics are fine, you could even get away with two:

```
`set xtics 1e6`
```

Sadly gnuplot lacks an option to set the number of tics explicitly.

Comment: I don't know how one could implement setting the number of tics (in the context of the current behavior with autoscaling to the next ticstep etc.) Do you know of any programs or plotting libraries which can do this properly?